# problema bootstrap.css al vincular no carga misEstilos.css

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

estoy comenzado con bootstrap y me he topado con un inconveniente
Tengo un html y le agrege un archivo llamado menu2.css para agregarle color a la pagina

```
<link href="misEstilos/menu2.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Hice una ventana modal la cual aparece al seleccionar una opcion del menu

Uno de los problemas es que cuando vinculo 
`<link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">` la pagina no carga el archivo de menu2.css y me ordena bien el contenido de la ventana modal, pero por el contrario si agrego 
`<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">` si me carga el archivo menu2.css pero no me ordena el contenido de la ventana modal

Me podrian orientar que estoy haciedo mal o como puedo solucionar este pequeño detalle

Comment: ¿Podrías mostrar como estás añadiendo esos estilos actualmente y en que orden? El orden a la hora de insertar los estilos en el html importa y deberías de agregar tu hoja de estilos misEstilos.css en último lugar.

Comment: Toma en cuenta que estás usando rutas relativas a la página que llama a la hoja de estilos. Tal vez eso tenga algo que ver.